# How to add a custom WatermarkGenerator to a WatermarkStrategy

Tags: apache-flink

I'm using Apache **Flink 1.11** and want to **use some custom WatermarkGenerator**.

With the Watermarkstrategy, you can add built-in WatermarkGenerators with ease:

```
WatermarkStrategy.forMonotonousTimestamps();

WatermarkStrategy.forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

In the documentation, you can see how to implement a custom Watermarkgenerator, for example a Periodic WatermarkGenerator:

```
public class BoundedOutOfOrdernessGenerator implements WatermarkGenerator<MyEvent> {

    private final long maxOutOfOrderness = 3500; // 3.5 seconds

    private long currentMaxTimestamp;

    @Override
    public void onEvent(MyEvent event, long eventTimestamp, WatermarkOutput output) {
        currentMaxTimestamp = Math.max(currentMaxTimestamp, eventTimestamp);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPeriodicEmit(WatermarkOutput output) {
        // emit the watermark as current highest timestamp minus the out-of-orderness bound
        output.emitWatermark(new Watermark(currentMaxTimestamp - maxOutOfOrderness - 1));
    }

}
```

**How can i add this custom BoundedOutOfOrdernessGenerator  to a Watermarkstrategy?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WatermarkStrategy is the thing you need to define. So assuming you have some class `MyWatermarkGenerator` that implements `WatermarkGenerator<MyEvent>`, then you'd do something like:

```java
        WatermarkStrategy<WatermarkedRecord> ws = (ctx -> new MyWatermarkGenerator());

    ...
    DataStream<MyEvent> ds = xxx;
    ds.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(ws);
```

Note that unless your source is setting up timestamps for you (e.g. Kafka record timestamps), you'll want to add a timestamp extractor to your WatermarkStrategy, as in...

```java
        WatermarkStrategy<WatermarkedRecord> ws = (ctx -> new MyWatermarkGenerator());
        ws = ws.withTimestampAssigner((r, ts) -> r.getTimestamp());
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. And where is the ctx (Context i think) defined, which is used in the lambda function? And where is this documented in the Flink Java Docs, that a WatermarkGenerator returns a WatermarkStrategy?

Comment: See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/eventtime/WatermarkStrategy.html. Note that there's a different WatermarkStrategy which is part of the Table API. The lambda expression is for the `createWatermarkGenerator()` call. And yes, it's confusing, I wound up wandering through the Flink source code.